# Ansible for Windows : WinRM, How to remove -NonInteractive from win_command or win_shell modules?

Tags: powershell, ansible, winrm

```
Using module file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_scheduled_task.ps1
<xx.xx.xxx.x> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: ak on PORT 5986 TO xx.xx.xxx.x
checking if winrm_host xx.xx.xxx.x is an IPv6 address
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM CONNECT: transport=basic endpoint=https://xx.xx.xxx.x:5986/wsman
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM OPEN SHELL: 0D4636FD-D80A-42AD-AB4B-D1F4DFD24EC1
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM EXEC 'PowerShell' ['-NoProfile', '**-NonInteractive**', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-']
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM RESULT u'<Response code 0, out "{"changed":false}\r\n", err "">'
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM STDOUT {"changed":false}

<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM STDERR 
<xx.xx.xxx.x> WINRM CLOSE SHELL: 0D4636FD-D80A-42AD-AB4B-D1F4DFD24EC1
ok: [xx.xx.xxx.x] => {
"changed": false
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

The above output is from ansible for windows verbose logs. I am seeing that the WinRm has a default option of  **-NonInteractive** to powershell command, which is hiding the interactive user interface. Is there any way where I can specify or mention not to use **-NonInteractive** for the powershell commands?

Comment: did you find any solution for that?